# Client Object Model and 32 bit

Tags: development, client-object-model

While trying out Client Object Model, I was wondering whether will there be any issues if the 'Platform Target' is NOT set to 64 bit? I tried setting the value to 32 bit, even then the application was working as expected.

My question is that; is the 'Platform Target' value of any importance to 'SharePoint client apps'. Will there be any implications rising out of this setting if set to 32-bit?

Answer (score 2):

Why not set the platform target to any CPU. That'll always work..

Comment: Thanks for your response. BTW I was searching for any known issues, If I set the 'Platform Target' to 32-bit. –